# Spring Property placeholder value of a value

Tags: spring, properties, dependency-injection, dependency-properties

I am trying to find if this is possible: I want t have a property file say

`

```
prop.properties: 
classDefA=com.ClassA
classDefB=com.ClassB
classDefC=com.ClassC

classType=classDefA  #or may be classType=classDefB ...

application-context.xml :
...
   <bean id="beanToUse" class="${classType}" />
...
```

`

Here if in the prop file, if i did classType=classDefA, i want it to put com.ClassA.
One of the reason I am exploring this route is because i only want the class loader to load one of the class based on value in the property file

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into Spring profiles?

http://blog.springsource.com/2011/02/11/spring-framework-3-1-m1-released/

You can define bean definitions with different profile names and specify which profile you want to use at initialization.

Comment: Yes, I have looked into bean profiles. But was curious if we can resolve a property value of a property somehow :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<util:properties id="props" location="application.properties"/>
<bean id="beanToUse" class="#{props['classType']}" />
```

Comment: i am already using a property place holder when i did it with "#{['classType']}", no luck it couldn't resolve it.

Comment: It's not a Spring property placeholder, it's an EL expression into the Properties instance.  Look again at the XML.